# Uniform Convergence of integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

If a sequence of functions $f_n$ are uniformly convergent in a given interval $[a,b]$ to a function $f$, are all riemann integrable, then the integral $$\int ^b_af_ndx\rightarrow\int^b_afdx$$ and $f$ is riemann integrable. but is the convergence uniform?

More precisely, is it true that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N:\forall n>N$,
$$\left| \int ^b_af_ndx-\int^b_afdx\right|<\epsilon$$

How would I prove it? Or is it obvious?

Comment: It does not really make sense to say that the convergence of the integrals is uniform. They converge, that's all.

Comment: OK, but isn't integral itself a function given the primitive exists?

Comment: Yes $\int_a^xg(t)dt$ is a function of $x$. But here, you only consider $\int_a^bg(t)dt$. Note that the bounds are fixed.

Comment: That makes it more clear. thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is tautological. By definition, $\int_a^b f_n$ tends to $\int_a^bf$ means the $\epsilon$ condition you are trying to prove. So if you already know the convergence, there is nothing to do. But actually, I suggest you prove that $\int_a^b f_n$ tends to $\int_a^bf$. It will be a good exercise to clarify these notions.

Hint: the integral is linear and
$$
|\int_a^bg(t)dt|\leq \int_a^b|g(t)|dt\leq (b-a)\sup_{t\in[a,b]}|g(t)|=(b-a)\|g\|_\infty.
$$

Comment: That's the uniform norm, $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|g(t)|$. That $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ means precisely that the sequence $\|f-f_n\|_\infty$ tends to $0$.

Comment: I think for the proof you suggest, noticing $\|\int^b_a(f_n-f)dx\|\le\int^b_a\|f_n-f\|dx<\int\epsilon/(b-a)$ will suffice. Thank you, it was very helpful.

Comment: I wanted to prove the above result(uniform convergence) because I want exchange two limits before integral, e.g. when you have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\int^m_af_ndx$. my concern was exchange of possible if and only if integrals are uniformly convergent. But since they are numbers, can I take it for granted and exchange limits?

Comment: Yes. Since your bounds are fixed and you have uniform convergance of the integrands, you can swap limit and integral. That's exactly what $\int_a^bf_n\longrightarrow\int_a^bf$ says.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't make sense to speak of uniform convergence in this context. The integrals $$I_n := \int_a^b f_n(x) \, dx \qquad \qquad I:=\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$$ are real numbers which do not depend on another parameter (since $a,b$ are fixed). $$I_n = \int_a^b f_n(x) \, dx \to I=\int_a^b f(x) \, dx \qquad (n \to \infty)$$ is (by the definition of convergence of sequences) equivalent to the following statement: $$\forall \varepsilon>0 \, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \geq N: |I_n - I| \leq \varepsilon \\ \Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon>0 \, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \geq N: \left|\int_a^b f_n(x) \, dx - \int_a^b f(x) \, dx \right| \leq \varepsilon$$