# Study the uniform convergence of $ I(\alpha)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\alpha^2-\sin^2\varphi)\mathrm{d}\varphi, $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

> Study the uniform convergence w.r.t. $\alpha$ of the following integral with parameters:
> $$
> I(\alpha)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\alpha^2-\sin^2\varphi)\mathrm{d}\varphi,
> $$
> where $\alpha\geq 1$.

I just learned integral with parameters. When $\alpha=1$, $\varphi=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a singularity point (we can actually compute the integral), when $\alpha>1$, the integral is proper. I do not how to solve the combined situation.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/324677/595055) may be relevant.

Comment: Hint: work on $|I(\alpha)-I(1)|$.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use Feynman trick ?
$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\alpha^2-\sin^2(\varphi))\,d\varphi$$
$$I'(\alpha)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac {2\alpha}{\alpha^2-\sin^2(\varphi)}\,d\varphi=-\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{\alpha^2-1}}$$